# store .Find results in an Array

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I store .find results in an array?

This macro using wildcards to find each string which occurs between `&lt;sm&gt` to `&lt;fin&gt`

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "&lt;sm&gt?&lt;fin&gt"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False

End With
```

and this part counts how many `&lt;sm&gt` exists in the text to define an array length:

```
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim NumSm As Long
    Dim TargetText As String
    TargetText = "&lt;sm&gt"
    J = 1
    I = 1
    While I > 0
    I = InStr(J, ActiveDocument.Range.Text, TargetText)
    If I > 0 Then
    NumSm = NumSm + 1
    J = I + 1
    End If
    Wend

    Dim SmArr() As Variant
    ReDim SmArr(0 To NumSm)
```

I would like to store find results in an array: `SmArr()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim i As Long, SmArr()
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "&lt;sm&gt*&lt;fin&gt"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve SmArr(i)
    SmArr(i) = Split(Split(.Text, "&lt;fin&gt")(0), "&lt;sm&gt")(1)
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
For i = 1 To UBound(SmArr)
  MsgBox SmArr(i)
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was a bit hard to understand, however I will try as best I can. Have you considered using a collection instead? with a collection you wont have to worry about defining array lengths.

```
Dim newColl as new collection
```

I would add items to the collection with a key so that you can still pick a choose the data to read as you would with an array.

```
newColl.add I, NumSm
```

NumSm being your key, to retrieve an item:

```
newColl.item X
```

or just iterate through a collection

```
Dim collObj as object

for each collObj in newColl
'stuff
next collObj
```